# Dimension of subvector space

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be an $n$ dimensional real vector space and $V^*$ be a it's dual vector space.There exsists a natural non-degenerate symmetric bilinear form in $V\oplus V^*$ given by:
\begin{equation}
(v+\xi, u+\eta)=\frac{1}{2}\{\xi(u)+\eta(v)\} , v,u \in V, \xi, \eta \in V^* 
\end{equation}
A subspce L in $V\oplus V^*$ is called a maximal isotropic subspace if $L$ is an $n$ dimensional space and null with respect to the bilinear form ,i.e
\begin{equation}
(X,Y)=0, \ \forall X,Y \in L
\end{equation}
Show that if $L$ is a maximal isotropic subspace of $V\oplus V^*$,then the parity of dimension of $L$ corresponds with the parity of dimension of $L\cap V$,i.e
\begin{equation}
\dim{L}\equiv \dim{L\cap V}(\mod 2).
\end{equation}

Comment: This claim, as phrased at the moment, can't be true. Just take $V^*$ as a subspace whenever $n$ is odd.

Comment: Certainly, you are correct.Thank you.